# PyQt4 Constantly Updating Text

Tags: python, pyqt

I have made a program that fetches the Olympic Scores and Displays Canada's Rank and amount of medals. How would i have this display in a GUI window with PyQt4 and have it constantly update?

Here is the Code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):      

        self.text = '?????'

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 280, 170)
        self.setWindowTitle('Draw text')
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('web.png'))
        self.show()

    def medal_update(self):
        html = urllib.request.urlopen("http://olympics.cbc.ca/medals/index.html")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
        Rank = soup.find(cns='Canada').find_previous('td').find_previous('td').text
        Rank = int(Rank)
        Rankend='st'
        if Rank==1:
            Rankend='st'
        elif Rank==2:
            Rankend='nd'
        elif Rank==3:
            Rankend='rd'
        elif Rank > 3:
            Rankend='th'
        else:
            Rankend='dey more dan 10th'
        self.Gold = soup.find(text='CAN').find_next('td').text
        Silver = soup.find(text='CAN').find_next('td').find_next('td').text
        Bronze = soup.find(text='CAN').find_next('td').find_next('td').find_next('td').text
        print ("Canada is in " + str(Rank) + str(Rankend) + ' Place')
        print ('They Have ' + Gold + ' Gold')
        print('They Have ' + Silver + ' Silver')
        print('They Have ' + Bronze + ' Bronze')


    def paintEvent(self, event):

        qp = QtGui.QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        self.drawText(event, qp)
        qp.end()

    def drawText(self, event, qp):

        qp.setPen(QtGui.QColor(200, 100, 3))
        qp.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Decorative', 20))
        qp.drawText(event.rect(), QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, self.text)        


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: If you know pyqt, try something and come back when you face a problem you can't solve. If you don't know pyqt, go read a basic pyqt tutorial and then try. Again, come back when you face a specific problem you can't solve.

Comment: @M4rtini I tried to post the code I've already written but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit the end of `medal_update` like this:

```
    self.text = ''
    self.text += ("Canada is in " + str(Rank) + str(Rankend) + ' Place' + '\n')
    self.text += ('They Have ' + Gold + ' Gold' + '\n')
    self.text +=('They Have ' + Silver + ' Silver' + '\n')
    self.text +=('They Have ' + Bronze + ' Bronze' + '\n')
    self.update()
```

And then put `medal_update` in a infinite loop of some sorts. Possible with some kind of delay\sleep time.

like this for example:

```
    self.my_timer = QtCore.QTimer()
    self.my_timer.timeout.connect(self.medal_update)
    self.my_timer.start(60000) #1 min intervall
```

complete code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
# from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):      

        self.text = '?????'
        self.medal_update()
        self.my_timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.my_timer.timeout.connect(self.medal_update)
        self.my_timer.start(60000) #1 min intervall

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 400, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Draw text')
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('web.png'))
        self.show()

    def medal_update(self):
        html = urllib.urlopen("http://olympics.cbc.ca/medals/index.html")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
        Rank = soup.find(cns='Canada').find_previous('td').find_previous('td').text
        Rank = int(Rank)
        Rankend='st'
        if Rank==1:
            Rankend='st'
        elif Rank==2:
            Rankend='nd'
        elif Rank==3:
            Rankend='rd'
        elif Rank > 3:
            Rankend='th'
        else:
            Rankend='dey more dan 10th'
        Gold = soup.find(text='CAN').find_next('td').text
        Silver = soup.find(text='CAN').find_next('td').find_next('td').text
        Bronze = soup.find(text='CAN').find_next('td').find_next('td').find_next('td').text
        self.text = ''
        self.text += ("Canada is in " + str(Rank) + str(Rankend) + ' Place' + '\n')
        self.text += ('They Have ' + Gold + ' Gold' + '\n')
        self.text +=('They Have ' + Silver + ' Silver' + '\n')
        self.text +=('They Have ' + Bronze + ' Bronze' + '\n')
        self.update()


    def paintEvent(self, event):

        qp = QtGui.QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        self.drawText(event, qp)
        qp.end()

    def drawText(self, event, qp):

        qp.setPen(QtGui.QColor(200, 100, 3))
        qp.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Decorative', 20))
        qp.drawText(event.rect(), QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, self.text)        


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll try that and see what i can do.

Comment: The only trouble i am having is actually setting the text to that value and have it update

Comment: ahh, seems like you have to add `self.update()` at the end of the function to force the gui to update. I resized the window and seems like that forced an update, and is why i did not notice it.

Comment: yeah it's working for me. i can post the whole code i guess. I was using PySide instead of PyQt but they should be equal as far as i know.

Comment: they should be the same in terms of the way it updates. That would be really great if you could post the whole code :)

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help and explaining to me what to do. I tried your code and it worked! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Suggest use `QTimer` to do interval update. Reference: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtimer.html